# restore a file, which was deleted in my local git repository

Tags: github

I accidentally deleted a ReadMe.txt document from my local git repository before I committed it. I can not find it in my trash bin. I can I restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the deletion has not been committed, than command below will restore the deleted file in the working tree.

```
$ git checkout -- <file>
```

You can get a list of all the deleted files in the working tree using the following command.

```
$ git ls-files --deleted
```

If the deletion has been committed, find the commit where it happened, then recover the file from this commit.

```
$ git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- <file>
$ git checkout <commit>^ -- <file>
```

In case you are looking for the path of the file to recover, the following command will display a summary of all deleted files.

```
$ git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```